# java: warning: iterator is a raw type

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, iterator

I don't understand why my code have a warning like this, this is my code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
     response.setContentType("text/html");  
     PrintWriter out=response.getWriter(); 
    try {

             InputStream csvfile = null;

             FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

             ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
             Map<String, List<FileItem>> file = upload.parseParameterMap(request);
             
             Iterator entries = file.entrySet().iterator();
             while (entries.hasNext()) {
                  Entry thisEntry = (Entry) entries.next();
                  List<FileItem> value = (List) thisEntry.getValue();
                    for (FileItem uploadItem : value) {
                        csvfile = uploadItem.getInputStream();
                      }  // end of for loop
             }//while

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(csvfile);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
           
            String text = "";
            reader.readLine();
```

I am getting the warning :`iterator is a raw type. references to generic type iterator e`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Iterators are parameterized types.

```
Iterator entries = file.entrySet().iterator();
```

Should be:

```
Iterator< Entry< String, List<FileItem> > > entries = file.entrySet().iterator();
```

The iterator should be of type `Entry<...>` because the entry set returns a set of entries from the map. The `...` Should be the same types as your map. In your case:

```
// Type of map
Map<String, List<FileItem> > 

// Type of entries
Entry< String, List<FileItem> >

// Type of iterator
Iterator< Entry< String, List<FileItem> > >
```

Instead of getting the iterator and calling `hasNext()`, let java do that for you via the enhanced for-loop:

```
// Just get the entry set, not the iterator
Set< Entry<String, List<FileItem> > > entrySet = file.entrySet();

// Java will inject the iterator, hasNext(), etc for you
// This reads: "For each entry of type XYZ in entrySet, do the following..."

for (Entry< String, List<FileItem> > entry : entrySet) {

    // Get the list from entry, entry is the result of entrySet.next()
    List<FileItem> list = entry.getValue();

    // Nested enhanced for loop use another iterator
    for (FileItem uploadItem : list) {

        csvfile = uploadItem.getInputStream();
    }  
}
```

Comment: like this ?  Iterator< Entry< String, List<FileItem> > > entries = file.entrySet().iterator();
              while (entries.hasNext()) {
               Entry< String, List<FileItem> > thisEntry = (Entry< String, List<FileItem> >) entries.next();
                   List<FileItem> value = (List<FileItem>) thisEntry.getValue();
                   for (List<FileItem> value1 : file.values()) {
                      for (FileItem uploadItem : value1) {
                           csvfile = uploadItem.getInputStream();
                      }

Comment: You should not need to cast. That's the reason you put the type in the `<>` angle brackets. If you take the second line of code I wrote, you should be able to safely erase all the casting. Also, you can use the enhanced for loop for cleaner syntax when looping through the entry set.

Comment: @KenKaneki updated answer to include use-case

Comment: im not expert about my english, really thanks for youre help, can you tell me simplify please

Comment: Using `iterator()` is not necessary. Using this syntax `for (Object obj : collection) { ... }` has the same effect as using `while (iterator.hasNext()) { iterator.next() ... }`, but the first one uses less code because Java calls `iterator(), hasNext() and next()` for you so you don't have to.

Comment: @KenKaneki But regarding the original question, it's because you didn't add the stuff between `<>`, if you want, you can leave the code as is. My suggestion was just to write it in less lines

Comment: im realy thanks to you for youre help, now im understand

Answer (score 0):

Change `Iterator` to `Iterator<Entry<String, List<FileItem>>>`, and similarly change `Entry` to `Entry<String, List<FileItem>>`.

But it looks like you really want to loop over values in the map `files`. In that case, just use `files.values()`. There's no need to use any `Iterator` or `Entry`, the following replaces your entire `while` loop:

```
for (List<FileItem> value : files.values()) {
    for (FileItem uploadItem : value) {
         csvfile = uploadItem.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

Your complete code looks like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        InputStream csvfile = null;
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        Map<String, List<FileItem>> file = upload.parseParameterMap(request);

        for (List<FileItem> value : files.values()) {
            for (FileItem uploadItem : value) {
                 csvfile = uploadItem.getInputStream();
            }
        }

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(csvfile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String text = "";
        reader.readLine();
```

Comment: my error is : duplicate local variable value from my edited code like this :  for (List<FileItem> value : file.values()) {
                      for (FileItem uploadItem : value) {
                           csvfile = uploadItem.getInputStream();
                      }
                   }

Comment: @KenKaneki The double-`for`-loops in my question replace your entire `while` loop. There shouldn't be any duplicate local variables.

Comment: im not expert about my english, really thanks for youre help, can you tell me simplify please

Comment: @KenKaneki See my edit. Copy the code, it will work.

Comment: im realy thanks to you for youre help, now im understand

Comment: that code you give me, get the erorr java.lang.NullPointerException, can you tell me how to solve this?

Comment: @KenKaneki You need to write another question with more context.